# Why ServiceStack.Redis throw error instead of trying to connect to another read instance?

Tags: caching, redis, servicestack

I successfully installed Redis on two machines and made then work as Master-Slave.
I tested some code to check if replication work and everything is ok.

My client manager looks like

```
var manager = new PooledRedisClientManager(new[] { "MasterIP:6379" }, new[] { "MasterIP:6379", "SlaveIP:6379" });
```

But now i shutdown my master instance and when i test my code again i get an error like client cant connect to Master server.

p.s For read i use GetReadOnlyCacheClient();

I repeated my code and i notice that client first is getting Master (error cant connect), then  when i run my code again client is getting Slave, then again when i run my code client is getting master and so on.

I downloaded source code on ServiceStack.Redis client. I just wanted to check when that error happens and here is the code.

```
private void Connect()
    {
        socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
        {
            SendTimeout = SendTimeout,
            ReceiveTimeout = ReceiveTimeout
        };
        try
        {
            if (ConnectTimeout == 0)
            {
                socket.Connect(Host, Port);
            }
            else
            {
                var connectResult = socket.BeginConnect(Host, Port, null, null);
                connectResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(ConnectTimeout, true);
            }

            if (!socket.Connected)
            {
                socket.Close();
                socket = null;
                return;
            }
            Bstream = new BufferedStream(new NetworkStream(socket), 16 * 1024);

            if (Password != null)
                SendExpectSuccess(Commands.Auth, Password.ToUtf8Bytes());

            db = 0;
            var ipEndpoint = socket.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
            clientPort = ipEndpoint != null ? ipEndpoint.Port : -1;
            lastCommand = null;
            lastSocketException = null;
            LastConnectedAtTimestamp = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();

            if (ConnectionFilter != null)
            {
                ConnectionFilter(this);
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            if (socket != null)
                socket.Close();
            socket = null;

            HadExceptions = true;
            var throwEx = new RedisException("could not connect to redis Instance at " + Host + ":" + Port, ex);
            log.Error(throwEx.Message, ex);
            throw throwEx;
        }
    }
```

I really dont understand this code, couze project is really big, but i think there is no *If this server fails, then try to get from another host in read only server list if any other exist*

I can make some kind of mine custom logic to check if fail to try to get another read only instance..but isnt this client supported to be ready about this issue?